# How to compute mutual information between two samples when some features are discrete and some are continuous?

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

If we need to compute mutual information between two features (columns) where each feature can only be either continuous or discrete, it's easy to compute mutual information between them using `scikit-learn`'s `mutual_info_classif` or `mutual_info_regression`.

However, if we were to compute mutual information between two samples (rows) and both samples contain values for continuous features and discrete features. Since the two rows both mixed data type, how does one compute the mutual information between them ?

Do I have to generate `k-1` columns in the dataframe that contains a discrete feature with `k` features and compute mutual information as if all values are continuous? Apologies for the clumsy explanation. Please let me know if i need to further clarify my question

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'continuous':np.random.normal(10,10,100),'discrete':np.random.randint(0,10,100)})
    continuous  discrete
0    16.620011         9
1    28.822962         8
2    19.706000         9
3     7.280422         1
4     1.665330         4
..         ...       ...
95    6.841500         6
96   12.245043         8
97   24.645107         1
98   17.333605         8
99   -9.638961         5
```

Now computing the mutual information between "continuous" column and "discrete" column in the example above is easy. However, if i want to compute the mutual information between sample 0 (row 0) and sample 99 (row 99), how should i take care of the discrete values and compute mutual information between these 2 samples? Do I just compute it as is ? Or do I need to give special treatment to the discrete values first and transform the dataframe, i.e. one hot encode the discrete column first and transform the dataframe (see below)?

```
    continuous  discrete_0  discrete_1  ...  discrete_7  discrete_8  discrete_9
0    16.620011         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         1.0
1    28.822962         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         1.0         0.0
2    19.706000         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         1.0
3     7.280422         0.0         1.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0
4     1.665330         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0
..         ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...         ...
95    6.841500         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0
96   12.245043         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         1.0         0.0
97   24.645107         0.0         1.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0
98   17.333605         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         1.0         0.0
99   -9.638961         0.0         0.0  ...         0.0         0.0         0.0
```

Or I just simply cannot compute mutual information between two samples when they contain mixed data types?

Comment: Please provide a concrete example for clarity.

Comment: added an example above. Let me know if it's still unclear.